# Why does this line not compile?

Tags: c++, stl

The following code doesn't compile ( Ideone link : https://ideone.com/DKI9Fm ). Why?:

**EDIT**: As per [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) of `std::map`, `const Key&` type is accepted by `std::map::find`. So passing `const int*` to `find()` should be okay.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class ConstDemo
{
    std::map<int*, int> m_Map;

public:
   ConstDemo(int count, int* pArray)
   {
       for(int i=0; i < count; ++i)
       {
          m_Map.insert(std::make_pair(&(pArray[i]),0));
       }

   }

   bool Find(const int* i) const
   {
       // DOESN"T COMPILE!
       return (m_Map.find(i) != m_Map.end());
   }


};


int main() {

    int a[10];
    ConstDemo cd(10, a);
    if(cd.Find(&a[5]))
       cout << "Found!" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read this far: _/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:1079:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
prog.cpp:22:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘std::map<int*, int>::key_type {aka int*}’_

Comment: A pointer as key in a map is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`const int*` and `int* const` aren't same. Try changing it to `int* const`:

```
bool Find(int* const i) const
```

This is because your `key_type` is `int*` (`std::map<int*, int> m_Map;`). And `m_Map.find` expects a `const key_type` as a parameter, i.e., `int* const` in your case. But you're passing a `const int**`.

If you pass a `int*` to `m_Map.find`, it would be okay too, because it can convert an `int*` to `int* const`, but it can't convert `int*` to `const int*`.

And also, there's a semicolon missing at the end of the following line int `main`:

```
ConstDemo cd(10, a)
```

Now, see it here on [Ideone](https://www.ideone.com/kG7ZPZ).

**EDIT**:

After the edit in your question

> As per documentation of `std::map`, `const Key&` type is accepted by `std::map::find`. So passing `const int*` to `find()` should be okay.

`const Key&` is a constant `Key`, so in your case, you need to pass a constant 
`int*` now. But `const int*` doesn't define a constant `int*`, it merely defines a pointer to `const int`. `int* const` defines a constant `int*`, so that's why it's giving error if you pass `const int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Use

```
bool Find(int* i) const { ... }
```

---

Long answer:

The declarations of `std::map::find` until C++11:

```
iterator find( const Key& key );
const_iterator find( const Key& key ) const;
```

The argument type is `const Key&`, not `Key` or `Key&`.

In your case, `Key` is `int*`, not `cons int*`,

If we substitute `Key` in the declarations, they look like:

```
iterator find( int * const & key );  // Not "const int*&"
                                     // That's unforunate part
const_iterator find( int * const & key ) const;
```

Such a function cannot be called with an variable whose type is `const int*`. That would allow the function to break the `const`-ness of the object that the pointer points to.